# No symbols loaded for MVVM viewmodel when trying to debug

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, mvvm, visual-studio-2019

I have a WPF MVVM application, developed with Visual Studio, never had any such problems with it or any other such application.

I have my MainWindow.xaml and in it:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowDataContext/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

I put a breakpoint in `MainWindowDataContext.cs` but when I press F5 to start debugging the breakpoint isn't hit and it says that no symbols have been loaded.

Never had this issue, how do I make VS load symbols for the viewmodel so I can debug an ICommand I'm using?

Comment: One thought that comes to mind, check to be sure you compiled your application in Debug mode and not Release mode.

Comment: @quaabaam, thanks, that's definitely a possible oversight, but I checked - it's in Debug.

Comment: Common steps when I see this:  Make sure the project warning level (actually all project warning levels) are set to the highest  level, 5.  Then, do Build >> Clean Solution, then build again.  When you run in the debugger and it loads the module that contains MainWindowDataContext, debugger breakpoints should enable or you are using an out-of-date version